# Kafka streams commit offset semantics

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I just wanted to confirm something which i think is in between the line of the documentation. Would it be correct to say that **Commit** in kafka streams is independent of if the **offset/message** has been processed by the entire set of processing nodes of application topology, but solely depend on the commit interval ? In other words, where in typical kafka consumer application, one would commit when a message is fully processed as opposed to only fetch, in Kafka stream, simply being fetched is enough for the **commit interval** to kick in and commit that message/offset ? That is, even if that **offset/message** has not yet been processed by the entire set of processing node of the application topology ?

Or are message eligible to be committed, based on the fact that the entire set of processing node of the topology processed them, and they are ready to go out in a topic or external system.

In a sense the question could be sum up as, when are offset/messages, eligible to be committed in Kafka streams ? is it conditional ? if so what is the condition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have do understand that a Kafka Streams program, i.e., its `Topology` my contain multiple sub-topologies (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#stream-partitions-and-tasks). Sub-topolgies are connected via topics to each other.

A record can be committed, if it's fully processed by a sub-topology. For this case, the record's intermediate output is written into the topic that connects two sub-topologies before committing happens. The downstream sub-topology would read from the "connecting topic" and commit offsets for this topic.

Committing indeed happens based on `commit.interval.ms` only. If a fetch returns lets say 100 records (offsets 0 to 99), and 30 records are processed by the sub-topology when `commit.interval.ms` hits, Kafka Streams would first make sure that the output of those 30 messages is flushed to Kafka (ie, `Producer.flush()`) and would afterward commit offset `30` -- the other 70 messages are just in an internal buffer of Kafka Streams and would be processed after the commit. If the buffer is empty, a new fetch would be send. Each thread, tracks `commit.interval.ms` independently, and would commit all its tasks if commit interval passed.

Because committing happens on a sub-topology basis, it can be than an input topic record is committed, while the output topic does not have the result data yet, because the intermediate results are not processed yet by a downstream sub-topology.

You can inspect the structure of your program via `Topology#describe()` to see what sub-topologies your program has.

Comment: Mathias i understand very well the sub-topology breakdown of Kafka streams. I am very familiarize with how a topology is materialized, that some operator force internal topics and what not e.g when things need to be rekey such as groupby. I guess I just wanted to know when is a message eligible for commit. It seems you are saying, when the message had been written either to an internal topic or a user define output topic ? Is that correct ?

Comment: That is correct. Another possibility would be, if the message is "stuck" in the `suppress` buffer (that is also fault-tolerant via changelogging) and not ready to be emitted downstream.

Comment: Maybe just one quick clarification on this. What is the max.poll.interval.ms for internal consumer, does it follows the main source consumers ? is there a way to set it ? What happen if. what happens if the internal consumer do not poll on time ? Let say if an internal subtopology is very log. Let say, 16 join on topics that have been group by. a.join(t1.grouby).join(t2.grouby).join(t3.groupby)......

Comment: My understanding is that all the groupby operation will generate a taks for the rekey of each topic and their will be a talk aggregate and join a to all the rekey topics.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "internal consumer" -- Kafka Streams has one "main consumer" that read from all input and repartition topics. Additionally, there is the "restore consumer" (well, for restoring and maintaining StandbyTasks) and there may be the "global consumer" if you use global state/table. Restore and global consumer don't form a consumer group (but manual `assignment` instead of `subscription`) and thus `max.poll.interval.ms` does not apply to them.

Comment: Ah right right yes. It has to do with the fact that one stream thread execute mutltiple task in sequence, and there is one consumer and producer per stream thread right ? Or something close to that. I have confused, because i went to read agin your blog https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/,  and the diagram with the two subtopology make it look like each subtopology has its own consumer, which would mean a consumer per task, and that is def not the way it works. Please confirm that i got it right this time :) ?

Comment: So using my decomposition above, one task might really take very long time to execute and impact other capability to move forward. But generally speaking the point is, if the subtopology is log, one must watch out for the max.poll.interval right ?

Comment: That is correct. A StreamThread has one consumer and one producer and can execute multiple tasks. It subscribes to all input/repartition topics for all assigned tasks, and pipes the record through the task accordingly. -- And yes, if you have a single very long sub-topology, you need to make sure that processing a single record does not take longer than `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: If I am right, we will only poll when the processor the completed batch. Does that mean the whole batch should be processed through the sub topology before `max.poll.interval.ms`?

Comment: No. KafkaStreams might process only a partial batch, before it polls again and/or commits offsets.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax correct me if i am wrong,  but that sounds specific to kafka stream only. Typically, we process everything we polled before going back to poll again, and thus after committing everything that has been processed. So it is a bit strange that while whatever has been polled is not fully processed, that we go back to poll again. Why would that be ?

Comment: Also does pushing into a cache, count  as we can go back to poll ?  Or does comiting into a state store count as we can go back to poll, the record has been processed ?

Comment: Yes, it's Kafka Streams specific. -- One reason for polling again is timestamp synchronization if you have multiple inputs -- Kafka Streams tried to process data from both inputs interleaved in timestamp order. If one input buffer becomes empty, we try to fetch data for the other input (cf. `max.task.idle.ms`). -- A second reason is that users might configure a large "fetch size" but a too short "max poll interval" -- to avoid dropping out of the group, we might call `poll()` before all records are processed (for this case, we might actually `pause()` partitions if our buffer is already full)

Comment: `Also does pushing into a cache, count as we can go back to poll ? Or does comiting into a state store count as we can go back to poll, the record has been processed ?` -- That depends -- for caching in the DSL the answer the "no". If a record is stuck in a KTable cache, it's not fully processed yet. However, before we commit, we would `flush` all caches to ensure that everything is fully processed and nothing is stuck in a cache any longer. -- For a `put()` into a state store, if there is no "forward()" call, the record is considered fully processed though.

Comment: Given that state stores are assumed to be fault-tolerant, that approach is fine. If you later `get()` the record and call `forward()` it will become part of "fully processing the current/new input record" (for a lack of a better way to phrase it...)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax does that mean that in cases of bugs/corrupted data, an offset would be committed regardless of whether we managed to process the data or not? would it also work in cases of exceptions (trying to understand if we might end up reprocessing the same record over and over again in case of consistent failures)

Comment: If you don't swallow an exception but let it bubble into Kafka Streams runtime, offset's won't be committed. -- By default the thread would die and a rebalance would happen to assign the tasks to a different thread/instance (you can also use a handler to re-start the dies thread). In any case, if the error persists, you could end-up with infinite retries (based on the last committed offset which would be the starting point after each failure).

Comment: Increasing lag would be one indicator -- are more pro-active monitoring to reduce the number of retries (and duplicates in the output if you don't use exactly-once semantics) might be a good idea if you do restart threads (if you don't restart thread, eventually all thread would die anyway in a cascading manner, bringing processing to a halt).

Answer (score 2):

Whether using streams or just a simple consumer, the key thing is that auto-commit happens in the polling thread, not a separate thread - the offset of a batch of messages is only committed on the subsequent poll, and `commit.interval.ms` just defines the minimum time between commits, ie a large value means that commit won't happen on every poll.

The implication is that as long as you are not spawning additional threads, you will only ever be committing offsets for messages that have been completely processed, whatever that processing involves.

Comment: Thank you. I follow you well and it was a refreshing clarification. However i guess what i wanted to know to some degree, is what does that mean for kafka stream.

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped, and it should be equally true of streams - under the covers you are still dealing with standard consumers and producers, streams is just another layer over that underlying core, hence commit semantics are the same. A streams setup involves consuming messages from one or more topics, doing some  processing and then publishing to a topic, hence if auto-commit is used then a batch of consumed messages will only be committed after successful publish, when the next batch is consumed (and the meaning of successful publish depends on acks)